# android turn on hardwareAccelerate cause image broken and Mosaic area

Tags: android

[image]

As shown in the Gif file,At first the Activity enabled hardware acceleration, in a number of models (Samsung S6, Note5,serval Mtk Devices ) appears to be a picture of fragmentation, mosaic, the phenomenon is relatively in low probability, but after the emergence, as long as the process is not killed, every time you enter the page will be! Click on the top left ToggleBtn to close the View's hardware acceleration,then the problem disappears.
    Thank you for any help you can offer.(forgive me my poor english #_#!!)

Comment: The image of the damaged area are the same, about 20% of the top of the screen area!

Comment: This Activity is used to browse video and images, I used a ViewPager to hold composite View,dynamic change visible views . Layout is a bit complicated,but depth is less than 10.